# Expected id-expression - Compiling with g++

Tags: c++

I just wrote a program with a `Matrix` object inside the `main.cpp` file. Everything was fine.

Now I want to outsource the object into a `Matrix.cpp` file and `Matrix.h` header, but I have encountered an error.

I get the following compiler error:

> Matrix.cpp:5:15: error: expected id-expression before '(' token
>    Matrix::Matrix(int n_rows){

Matrix.h:

```
#ifndef Matrix
#define Matrix
#include "iostream"
#include "string"
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class Matrix{

  private:

    int n_rows;
    int* vect;

  public:
    Matrix(int);
};

#endif
```

Matrix.cpp:

```
#include "Matrix.h"

// Constructor
Matrix::Matrix(int n_rows){ //ERROR
    if(n_rows>0){

    this->n_rows = n_rows;
    this->vect = new int[n_rows];
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i = 0; i< n_rows; i++){
        this->vect[i] = rand() % 100;
        }
    }   
}
```

Maybe there is a keyword to this problem that I do not know jet. I would appreciate it if you could help me out.

NEW: Based on the accepted answer: Why is the the occurence `Matrix` substituted by a blank space?

Comment: You define a preprocessor constant `Matrix` at the top of your header, then reuse the same identifier for the class name. You should rename the preprocessor constant to eg. `MATRIX_H` or similar.

Comment: Not the issue but `#include "iostream"
#include "string"` should be `#include <iostream>
#include <string>`

Comment: Ty NathanOliver, I'll take that into account.

Comment: Unaffortunately I have the same problem, even after renaming the include from Matrix to MATRIX_H

Comment: Is the error message you show the *full* and *complete* output of the compiler? Copy-pasted? There's no "informational" messages? Nothing else (which might seem unrelated but maybe isn't)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#define Matrix` means that every occurrence of 'Matrix' will be replaced with nothing by the preprocessor.

Thus, your compiler sees this

```
using namespace std;

class {

  private:

    int n_rows;
    int* vect;

  public:
    (int);
};

::(int n_rows){ 
    if(n_rows>0){

    this->n_rows = n_rows;
    this->vect = new int[n_rows];
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i = 0; i< n_rows; i++){
        this->vect[i] = rand() % 100;
        }
    }   
}
```

But the error message refers to the code before preprocessing, which makes it pretty incomprehensible.

Include guards are conventionally all uppercase (as are macros in general).
You should do that, too.

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H
```

Comment: It started compiling, when I renamed the header from Matrix.h into MATRIX.h, does that make any sense? Ty

Comment: @PabloJeken You shouldn't rename the header, you should rename the include guard.

Comment: I did, but it did not change anything. Additionally renaming the header solved the errors.

Comment: @PabloJeken please take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)